# Kibana and groovy scripting

Tags: groovy, scripting, lucene, kibana-4

I was looking for a way to calculate a ratio on Kibana. After many researches i found this way :
Using the "JSON Input" feature in a visualisation.

I have all my informations in an index, with 2 types of documents (boots and reboots).
**I am looking for the script which count the number of documents with the type boots, same for the reboots type then divide the second by the first.**
It sounds really easy, but i do not find any way to get it after my researches, and i am not used to groovy enough **yet** to do it by myself.

I found many ways to manipulate documents values (doc['mydocname'].values etc), but nothing about the type.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I tried this

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "boots_count" : { "value_count" : { "_type" : "boots" } }
}
```

}
Which is supposed to count the number of fields (here the field _type) in the index. But when i put it into "JSON Input" in a visualisation, that results in an error :

Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[BbXJ0O6tRxa_OcyBfYCGJQ][informationbe][0]: SearchParseException[[informationbe][0]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"size\":0,\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"@sitePoste\",\"size\":5,\"order\":{\"1\":\"desc\"}},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"avg\":{\"script\":\"0\",\"lang\":\"expression\",\"ratio\":{\"boots_count\":{\"value_count\":{\"_type\":\"boots\"}}}}}}}}

I am wrong. But where ?

EDIT2 : In other hand, i am trying scripted fields, with something like this using lucene expression :

```
doc['_type:boots'].count / doc['_type:reboots'].count
```

but it doesnt work more, i am pretty confident about the "doc['_type:boots']" part, i guess the problem is on the "XXX.count" part.

After many attempts, i understand better and better how it works. Default scripted fields scope is on the document, not on the whole index, so i cant do a count action of whole values of the index from documents in it.
I am looking for a workaround, i'll post it it if find something interesting.

Comment: Do you have an example that is failing, and the error you're getting, or specific problem?

Comment: I have no failing or error yet, i am looking for building the script and i have no idea of the syntax :s
From my researches, i am thinking of something like it : index["type":"boot"].count but i found nothing equivalent yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem :

I added a scripted field, if the type of the document is boots, the scripted field = 1, else 0. Then i created a search with only boots and reboots documents (filter _type:boots _type:reboots) and calculated the average of the scripted field in a metric.

Everything works well !